# Как правильно назначать пользователя в группу?

Tags: linux, permissions

Я создал пользователя `testuser`, затем создал папку `test_folder`. Пользователь из под которого я работаю - `reiji`. Я добавил пользователя `reiji` в группу `testuser`. Папка `test_folder` принадлежит `testuser:testuser` и имеет права доступа `750`. Проблема в том что я хоть и добавил пользователя `reiji` в группу `testuser` - пользователь `reiji` по прежнему не может просматривать папку `test_folder`.

*Вопрос:* **Почему?**

Правки согласно комментарию

1. `sudo useradd testuser`
2. `sudo usermod -a -G testuser reiji`
3. `reiji : reiji adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare testuser`
4. 

```
total 12
drwxr-x--- 2 testuser testuser 4096 янв  8 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 reiji    reiji    4096 янв  8 20:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        6 янв  8 20:16 hello.find
```

5. `bash: cd: test_folder/: Permission denied`

Comment: 1. Какой командой создавал пользователя `testuser`? 2. Какой командой добавлял `reiji` в группу? 3. Что показывает команда `groups reiji`? 4. Что показывает команда `ls -al test_folder` ? 5. Что происходит при попытке войти в папку `test_fodler` от `reiji`?  (все эти данные добавь в тело вопроса)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, файл `hello.find` добавлял от `root` пользователя

Comment: @Reiji Akkerman Попробуйте перелогиниться

Answer (score 1):

По идее добавление в группу происходит черtз "кого - куда"

```
sudo usermod -aG reiji testuser
```

проверить добавление в группу testuser:

```
groups testuser
```

Должно точно показать кто в этой группе